# Promises/A - writing a function that complies with promises

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

Though I have known promises for quite sometime now, I am only really starting to use them (or create them) very recently.

My requirement is to create a promise compliant function, so that the caller can call and then chain it to other function calls.

a simple function like this...

```
/**
 *  Checks if a user is available in cache.  If avaialble, returns
 *  the hash object of this user.  If the cache is not enabled, or
 *  the user is not found in cache, it returns null object.
 *
 **/
function chkUserInCache(username, password, done) {
  var cacheKey = "partner:" + username;
  if (cache == null) return done(null);

  // Look for the user in the cache.
  cache.hgetallAsync(cacheKey).then(function(result){
    if (result === null) return done(null);
    else return done(null,result);
  });
}
```

And the calling function would call like:

```
chkUserInCache(u,p)
.then(result) {
   // do something
}).catch(function(e){
  // do something
});
```

At present, one way I know is to use Bluebird promise and then call promisify on my function, to get a wrapped promise compliant function object.

But if I have many such functions (say 6 to 10), should I keep calling promisifiy on each of these and store the returned objects somewhere and use it?

Or is there any other way?  Or, is there a native way of writing promise compliant code?

For a simple use case of < 10 utility functions, what would be the best approach, if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the appropriate promise API.

Given that `hgetAllAsync` is already a promise-returning function, there is no reason to promisify `chkUserInCache` or even use the `Promise` constructor. Instead, you should remove that `done` callback and just return the promise:

```
function chkUserInCache(username, password, done) {
  var cacheKey = "partner:" + username;
  if (cache == null) return Promise.resolve(null);

  // Look for the user in the cache.
  return cache.hgetallAsync(cacheKey);
}
```

Comment: Yes, precisely, I was looking for that kind of 3rd line which says "return Promise.resolve(value);  Still having some hangover probs trying to vade into javascript promises, coming from a c/c++/java background :)